# Canvas on top of <img/> tag

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to get the coordinates of X and Y of an image using canvas, the thing is that I want to put the image behind the canvas so I can use js with canvas on top of this image 
*"I don't want to draw this image on the canvas so I can change it easily using back end programming"*

```
<style>
  .map_image{width:80%; position:relative;}
  #map_canvas{width:100%; height:100%; position:static; top:0px; right:0px;}
  .map_img{width:100%; height:100%;}
</style>

<div class="map_image">
  <canvas id="map_canvas"></canvas>
  <img src="images/map.jpg" class="map_img" />
</div>
```

Using this code, the canvas appears behinde the image, and I used `z-index`, but it didn't work with me.

I hope it's clear for you, and if there is any other way I'll be pleased if you helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`z-index` applies to positioned elements i.e. ones with position (absolute, fixed, relative).

http://jsfiddle.net/66Ryg/

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem with position: static for canvas, try to change it to relative and try to apply z-index again and your image will be behind of canvas.

or you could try to apply position absolute for canvas.
Check the code here

```
.map_image{width:80%; position:relative;}
#map_canvas{width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; top:0px; right:0px;}
.map_img{width:100%;height:100%;}
```